# how to query class inheritance in c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, inheritance, reflection

is there any way to query how many class inherit a class using linq and reflection ?
eg. how to know classes that inherit from System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult in System.Web.Mvc.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to retrieve only classes, and not interfaces (IsAssignablefrom returns also interfaces), you should try

```
var t = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult);
var asmb = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);//or get all assemblies you need and put next code in loop
return asmb.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.IsSubClassOf(t)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two methods, 1. [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), 2. `assembly.GetTypes`:

```
var t = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult);
var asmb = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
return asmb.GetTypes().Where(x=>x.IsAssignableFrom(t) && x != t);
```

Comment: returns nothing . evaluated from linqpad .

Comment: @dfang You should add ToList() to return something, (I don't have anything in my PC (.net, linqpad, ...), but you can upload code on ideone.com we can check there).